# Getting my Monero off Kraken

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Trying to get my Monero off Kraken. I bit the bullet after waiting a couple months and installed Monerod 0.11.1.0 on an old Ubuntu box on my network. I downloaded the entire blockchain and installed the GUI on my Mac and attempted to connect thru rpc. Seems to connect, says "Connected" and log data shows correct IP. My balance is still zero after a small test transaction from Kraken over 4 hours ago. The transaction is listed at Kraken as "Sending".
I got the TxID from the Kraken website and searched for it on the Monero blockchain explorer - not found.
I realize there are a lot of variables here, but would appreciate some advice about next steps. Should I
 1. Wait, cuz Kraken is really slow at sending Monero
 2. Install the cli on the unix machine and see if my balance is nonzero there - ie eliminate a possible iMac -> Ubuntu connection problem. Checking the log file on the Mac shows lots of activity, looks like its connected however. 
 3. Move the downloaded blockchain to the Mac. Rather not, as I don't want to have my daily use machine grinding away at the blockchain, that was the idea behind repurposing the Ubuntu box.
 4. Other, on your wise advice.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Give it at least 24h first, I mean... it's Kraken.

Comment: Use that ^ guide to resolve your issue. If the transaction can't be found on a blockexplorer, it implies Kraken has not send it out yet.

Comment: ...and you're right dEBRUYNE and @Maxithi, it was a problem at Kraken's end and the transaction never made it to the blockchain. I resent another test transaction and it made it; then I sent the rest of my Monero. Finally have my Monero tucked away in my own wallet, feels good!